# Is there any difference between Groovy's non-argument grep() and findAll() methods?

Tags: groovy

From the Groovy JDK:

#### [public Collection grep()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#grep%28%29)

> Iterates over the collection of items which this Object represents and returns each item that matches using the IDENTITY Closure as a filter - effectively returning all elements which satisfy Groovy truth.

#### [public Collection findAll()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#findAll%28%29)

> Finds all items matching the IDENTITY Closure (i.e. matching Groovy truth).

Comment: Did you check the source? They're in `/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Short answer: the result will be the same.

Long answer:
`grep` normally uses a filter object, on which `isCase` is then called. As such the argument to grep normally is no Groovy Closure. For `findAll` you use a Closure as argument, and if the result of the Closure is evaluated to true, it is taken into the resulting collection.

Now it is important to know that a Closure has an isCase method as well. `Closure#isCase(Object)` will execute the Closure using the argument as argument for the Closure and the result of it is then evaluated using Groovy Truth. For an identity Closure, ie. `{it}`, this means the closure will return what is given to it, thus Groovy will apply *Groovy Truth* to the argument of the grep call. The result is then the same as with findAll.

Comment: I think the short answer should make it clear that the result is the same *when a closure is used* but `grep` can use other types of parameters.

Comment: If I understand [Pedro Witzel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44263091/45375) correctly, another, more important difference is that `grep` seemingly always returns an `ArrayList`, irrespective of the type of the input collection.

Answer (score 6):

Actually there is a slight difference between both. 
At least when using those methods with maps.

`grep` returns an `ArrayList`, when `findAll` returns a `Map`.

Here follows an example:

```
def l_map = [a:1, b:2, c:3]

def map_grep = l_map.grep { it.key == 'a' || it.value == 2}
def map_findAll = l_map.findAll { it.key == 'a' || it.value == 2}

println map_grep
println map_findAll

assert l_map instanceof Map
assert map_grep instanceof ArrayList
assert map_findAll instanceof Map
```

Comment: The difference is that grep returns a list but findAll return a collection which has same type with the origin one.